# React: How to use classes and additionally a variable class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple react component for a navigation element. This is how I was doing it so far.

It's really a simple question, but how do I add a variable value to the className set? In this example every element has the class `item` and the initial element additionally gets the class `active`

```
export default class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { activeTab: 'Initial' };
        this.setActiveClassOnTab = this.setActiveClassOnTab.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeTabs = this.handleChangeTabs.bind(this);
    }

    setActiveClassOnTab(tab) {
        return this.state.activeTab === tab ? 'active' : '';
    }

    handleChangeTabs(event) {
        this.setState({ activeTab: event.target.textContent });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ui compact menu">
                { this.props.menu.map((item) => {
                    return (<a className="item { this.setActiveClassOnTab(item.title) }" onClick={ this.handleChangeTabs } key={ item.title}>{ item.title }</a>);
                }) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ES6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) would be a nice, clear solution here:

```
<a className={`item ${this.setActiveClassOnTab(item.title)}`} onClick={ this.handleChangeTabs } key={ item.title}>{ item.title }</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

String templates is what you are looking for:

```
<a className={`item ${this.setActiveClassOnTab(item.title)}`} />
```

Anything you put between `${` and `}` will be evaluated and replaced on runtime, so you can dynamically insert the class you are looking for, without having to concatenate the string.

Comment: This will need curly brackets around the template literal though.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.